# Split sentence into words separated with commas

Tags: php

i have one sentence saved in database field , an i want to break it in words, but that words needs to be separated by coma, like this:

```
This, is, test, text
```

I tried something with explode() but it didnt do the work.

Comment: How did [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) not work? It's exactly what you need!

Comment: Why not us the build in function str_word_count(), then implode again to add the commas

Comment: Well, EXPLODE just explodes it, but i have no commas between words.

Comment: It's very vague what exactly you want. What is the exact input and what is the exact desired output?

Comment: If you want each word separately, you can explode it by space `explode(" ",$data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
$text = "This is test text";
echo str_replace (" ", ", ", $text); // This, is, test, text
```

Comment: The arguments are not in the correct order, should be: `str_replace(' ', ', ', $text);`

Comment: if `$text` has multiple spaces, the result is something like this: `This, , , is, , test, text`

Comment: beware, `"This  is test text"` will return `"This, , is, test, text"`. He might want to look for `preg_replace` instead.

Comment: @WouterH - no it doesnt - I just tested it

Comment: I typed two spaced between 'this' and 'is', but they are not visible

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `preg_split()` to split words based on at least one space in between (though an exclamation mark with surrounding spaces would also be considered a word); afterwards you stick them back together.

```
echo join(', ', preg_split('/\s+/', $str));
```

Alternatively, let `wordwrap` do the work for you, decorate and undecorate:

```
echo join(', ', explode("\0", wordwrap($s, 1, "\0")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the most  efficient way, but if you want to use explode, you'll need to use implode also:

```
<?php

$foo = 'this is a test';
$bar = implode(', ', explode(' ', $foo));
print_r($bar);

?>
```

would show : `this, is, a, test`